# Vue i18n - How do I get the current locale inside the i18n component options?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, localization, vue-i18n

I'm trying to expand the already loaded localizations for a specific component and I would like to do something like this:

```
export default {
  name: 'General',
  components: {
    Header,
    Content,
    NextPageButton
  },
  i18n: {
    messages: {
      [this.$i18n.locale]: { message: require('@/locales/' + this.$i18n.locale + '/tso/general.json') }
    }
  }
```

Problem is of course that the $i18n is undefined inside the i18n options. How can I retrieve the current locale here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the Vue instance like: `this.Vue.$i18n.locale`

Another way of access is `this.$root.$i18n.locale`

Comment: Can you import Vue from 'vue' ? Otherwise maybe also check the this.$root object

Comment: Thanks! this.$root.$i18n.locale did the trick! Is it bad practice to use?

Comment: No not in particular. In general try to keep i18n jobs top down, but I've also ran into a use case where i needed access from the component